# GoogleSignInOptions set prompt to consent

Tags: kotlin, google-signin

I've looked through the documentation but I can't seem to find the options for this. When using GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInOptions.Builder is there a way to set prompt = consent? Right now the refresh token is only returned the first time the call returns but if there is an error in storing it I need to be able to get it again, instead of it just automatically signing the user in and only giving an access token.